# Can I avoid a ValueError concatenating empty dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have `df = pd.concat(dict_of_df, axis=0)` and sometimes [rarely] it might be the case that all of the `df` in the dictionary are empty in which case I would like Pandas to cheerfully return an empty dataframe. But instead I get a ValueError.

I can write a loop to check for the length of each df before calling concat, but would prefer to not always do that, so at the moment I just embed the concat into a try/except... which doesnt make be really happy either because if there was a "true" ValueError I would like to have know it. So then I could do a try/except loop and if exception is thrown then do a count of all the dicts and ... ugh. This is getting crazy.

Is there something more clean? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm trying to reproduce the issue but was unable to obtain a `ValueError`; indeed, I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: Gosh Saiden, you are correct. That is exactly happening for me now when I create a test dataset.

Comment: Aha.... If a = None, b= None, the c = pd.concat([a,b]) fails

Answer (score 2):

I don't have this problem:

```py
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame()] * 3, axis=0)
```

What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am going to withdraw the question. I now realize that
`pd.concat([None,None])` produces the ValueError, whereas as noted above `pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame())` does exactly what you would hope. Also `pd.concat([None,pd.DataFrame()])` is fine too. So it's not really fair of me to complain about concat. I need to stop feeding my routine non-existent datasets !

Thanks for feedback